# Node.js upgrade from V4.x: how to find which functions in my code are unsupported in Node V6.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, migration

I am looking to upgrade my Node.js installation from V4.4.7 to V6.11.5. I was wondering how I could which functions in my code are unsupported in V6.x?

Perhaps VS Code has plugin that could help me in identifying these functions?

Is there a way ESLint can help?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The github page shows this: https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Breaking-changes-between-v5-and-v6

Comment: Have you tried running your code? Maybe theres no problem at all...

Comment: @pfg is there a 'programmatic' way to find this, instead of having to piece together v4-to-v5 and then v5-to-v6? Thanks

Comment: The programmatic way would be to run unit tests in node v6 that cover all your code and discover what (if anything) doens't work properly.  There is no magic capability in node.js to tell you what might not work in the version of node.js you're running.  Other than testing, you study release notes and grep for possible usage of things mentioned in release notes.

Comment: @jfriend00 -- Given that Javascript does dynamic type checking, it makes sense that it is not technically possible. I was hoping for some tool that would help me at least partially. Automated unit tests would be nice, but I am dealing with a bunch of legacy code without any. Thanks

Comment: Then it's study release notes to make a list of affected APIs and grep your codebase, fix and then test.  No other way that I know of.